# RuntimeError: You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run 'rails console' and I keep getting the following error message:

in `normalize_conditions!': You should not use the`match`method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (RuntimeError)
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add`via: [:get, :post]`option.
If you want to expose your action to GET, use`get` in the router:
  Instead of: match "controller#action"
  Do: get "controller#action"

I can't find the solution on Stack Overflow, what should I do?

My routes.rb file is:

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  resources :sessions,      only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts,    only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  # Named routes:
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

end
```

Comment: could you post your routes.rb file, please.

Answer (score 14):

sounds like you have an issue in your `routes.rb` file. Probably the first thing to do is comment any line that you're using a `match` route in; or, as the error message suggests, add `via: [:get, :post]` to its options.

Such as:

```
match 'path', :to => 'controller#action', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I have commented out all of the match lines, and the console is now working.

Comment: you are probably trying to run a rails 3 project in rails 4. Match without method has been removed from rails 4